# WIX won't copy DLL into system32 folder

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I need to copy a DLL into the `system32` folder, that's my WIX script but it doesn't work, the copy command just fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="LMBrick Service" Language="1033" Version="1.3.0.0"
           Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="3de1a175-3701-435f-90bc-e97cb66b5524">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="LMBrickServiceInstallation" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="LMBrickComponents" />
    </Feature>

    <CustomAction Id="InstallLMBrickDll" Directory="LMBRICKINSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"
                  ExeCommand="copy LMBrick.dll [System64Folder]LMBrick.dll"
                  Return="check" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>

      <Custom Action="InstallLMBrickDll" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="MyCompany">
          <Directory Id="App" Name="MyProduct">
            <Directory Id="LMBRICKINSTALLFOLDER" Name="LMBrickService">
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Comment: Why don't you do the copy using Wix and the msi?  That's what installer programs *do* - they copy files to the correct location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Actions that run Exes have to actually run an exe. However **copy** is not an exe; it's built into the command shell. So you have two immediate choices (and two better choices later):

- Find an actual exe, such as **xcopy.exe**, and run that instead, or
- Execute a shell such as **cmd.exe** with arguments that invoke its **copy** builtin.

You can confirm this by opening up a command prompt and executing the commands *where copy* and *where xcopy* respectively. Note that launching cmd.exe or any console program as an Exe will result in a console window flashing by during installation. This typically looks rather unprofessional, and you should use one of two alternatives:

- Wrappers such as [WixQuietExec](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html) can suppress the console window, or
- Built-in Windows Installer functionality, such as exposed through [CopyFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html), can avoid the need for a custom action at all.

If possible, it's best to avoid custom actions and use Windows Installer functionality. So aim for the last option if you can.

Comment: thank you very much! another question: I need to restart IIS during my WIX installation, how can I do that? I know I need a custom action but I can't find any WIX predefined path for the iisreset.exe executable. If you want more rep point I made a proper SO question, here the link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677549/how-to-restart-iis-from-wix