# How to restart IIS from WIX?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I need to restart IIS during my WIX installation, how can I do that?
I know I need a custom action but I can't find any WIX predefined path for the `iisreset.exe` executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need a custom action for this. You can use the [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) table and link it to the component that needs the IIS restart.